# [Debian][KDE] Can't get wireless to work

Tags: debian, wifi, kde

Before going into the problem I'd like to state that before this incident I had Debian with GNOME instead of KDE. 
I formatted to KDE today and now I am unable to get wireless to work. 
On the system tray icon it says that the WLAN Interface is Unmanaged:

> ### WLAN Interface
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | **Type:** | Wireless 802.11 |
> | **Connection State:** | Unmanaged |
> | **IP Address:** | No IP address. |
> | **Connection Speed:** | Unknown |
> | **System Name:** | wlan0 |
> | **MAC Address:** | 00:18:DE:94:6A:05 |
> | **Driver:** | iwl3945 |

<sup>[Manually transcribed from [this screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PrxS.png).]</sup>

My wireless card is this:

```
# dmesg | grep Wireless
[    7.918101] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[    7.980252] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

I tried adding wpa-ssid and wpa-psk under the iface wlan0 but it didn't work. 
I also installed firmware-linux-free.

```
firmware-linux-free is already the newest version.
```

I would appreciate any help; I am lost over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wireless card is supported in the `iwlegacy` driver which is in the non free repo

1. Add a "non-free" component to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, for example:

   ```
   deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
   ```
2. Update the list of available packages and install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
   ```
3. As the `iwlegacy` driver is automatically loaded for supported devices, reinsert driver modules to access installed firmware:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe -r iwl3945
   $ sudo modprobe iwl3945
   ```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlegacy

Comment: Indeed, I just discovered this before reading your answer. I fixed it by manually installing this: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/firmware-iwlwifi and setting /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf managed variable to true.